# Data Validation - List from range

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets one with my **Listings** which need to be assigned to a master category and a subcategory IF AVAILABLE. So I have two columns for my master category and the subcategory.

The second sheet, **Categories**, contains also two columns, one for each. The first column lists the master categories and the second column the subscategories which in some cases cells are empty.

I added a data validation on my **Listings** sheet column and I can select the Master Category from a dropdown list. What I would like to do is have a dropdown list to the Subcategory that pulls the subcategories from the **Categories** sheet but ONLY the ones that belong to the master category.

I tried to do it with a LOOKUP formula but the same formula that works OK in the sheet, returns a "Please enter a valid range" error.

Here is an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ukmc8T1jDsxWy5aQJZVU3q2YNJvUxaATOzvAvO7WdKA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222312/data-validation-list-from-range) & share a sample sheet with sample data.

Comment: You're right, Irwin. I just read again my description and it's kinda haotic. My english is out of practice.
I added a sample sheet. The text is in Greek though, I hope it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out. I was taking the wrong approach. I created a data validation for the first column that pulled all the categories. On the second column I added a VLOOKUP that brought the master category (if available).